# How can I begin calculating cumsum() on a specific date within a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

Is there a way to start computing `cumsum()` on a specific date within a Pandas dataframe?

Given the following dataframe, I am able to calculate the `cumsum()` for all of the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Date': '2022-01-01', 'Confirmed': 7 },
    {'Date': '2022-01-02', 'Confirmed': 4 },
    {'Date': '2022-01-03', 'Confirmed': 12 },
    {'Date': '2022-01-03', 'Confirmed': 2 },
    {'Date': '2022-01-04', 'Confirmed': 9 },
    {'Date': '2022-01-05', 'Confirmed': 10 },
])

df["Total Confirmed"]  = df["Confirmed"].cumsum()
```

[image]

However, I would like to calculate the `cumsum()` starting on a specific date.  For example, I would like to begin calculating `cumsum()` on the first occurrence of `2022-01-03` which would end up looking like this:

[image]

I noticed that there is the `shift()` property but that only seems to be specific to the number of rows and it still starts the `cumsum()` from the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
ser = df["Confirmed"].where(df["Date"].eq("2022-01-03").cummax(), 0)

df["Total Confirmed"] = ser.cumsum()
```

Another variant :

```
df.iloc[:df["Date"].eq("2022-01-03").idxmax()] = np.nan

df["Total Confirmed"] = df["Confirmed"].cumsum().fillna(0, downcast="infer")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

         Date  Confirmed  Total Confirmed
0  2022-01-01          7                0
1  2022-01-02          4                0
2  2022-01-03         12               12
3  2022-01-03          2               14
4  2022-01-04          9               23
5  2022-01-05         10               33
```

Answer (score 1):

`(df["Confirmed"] * (df["Date"] >= "2022-01-03")).cumsum()`